# Unable to clear cache on website (trying to add a new logo)

Tags: html, caching, cloudflare

I have run out of options here. I need to change the logo of the [site](http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/). This is a static website with lot of pages. I uploaded the logo to `/images/logo.png`on the web server via FTP.

However, I don't see the new logo, instead I still see the old logo. I am pretty much sure that I uploaded to the correct directory.

[Old Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNaXT.png)

This is what I have done so far.

1. I paused Cloudflare, nothing happened.
2. I emptied my .htaccess. nothing happened.

I get the new logo only via FTP not on HTTP :(
Any guess?

Comment: what you have done so far? update your question with your codes. such `html` and `css`

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell which is the new and which is the old logo. I'm getting a giant 5400x1528 file at http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/images/logo.png

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot?

Comment: Please send me the output of http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/images/logo.png

Comment: What's wrong with the link above? Anyways, it's a banner with 'Nano' in red and 'Informatics' in black, right below it: https://imgur.com/05HpqFX

Comment: That's the old logo. I have replaced this logo with a new logo, which is named exactly logo.png.

Comment: Tried renaming to newLogo.png? What happens then? Maybe it's some sort of cache on webserver? Please update your post to clearify that the red/black logo is WRONG. Hard to tell from your current post! BTW: In your Images folder, your current "logo.png" is the one with red/black.

Comment: Renaming works! However, I have many pages.It would be tiresome to replace everywhere!

Comment: I understand... Check out my answer to your post, maybe that will help you "refresh" the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Clear your local cache** - If you're trying to resolve the issue for yourself to see if the logo has been updated, then you can simply [clear the cache in your web browser](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/). If you want to clear the cache for everyone using your website then you need to adjust your .htaccess (but this will only update once the current cache settings have been expired).

**Option 2 - Trick the cache** - The best solution (but not the most practical for you in this case) is to change the name of the file loaded in the webpages. You don't need to change or modify the file itself, you can simply change the image url inside the web page from `"/images/logo.png"` to `"/images/logo.png?v2"` and that will make the browser think it is a new file, loading that file from fresh for you. (However this won't work if you have CloudFlare's caching level set to Ignore Query String or No Query String)

**Option 3 - Purge the cache** - As the other two comments have mentioned, [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) has an excellent cache purging system - and a [guide](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246) to go with it. I recommend only purging a specific file, but you can purge the whole website if you run into issue (although not advised on heavy traffic sites).

**Option 4 - Development mode** - One solution to use while editing content such as images and JS files is to activate developer mode on your CloudFlare dashboard. Which will temporarily bypass the CloudFlare caching system so you can see your changes in real-time. See the guide [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168246).

---

**Final note** - I would recommend setting up a global headers page and include that in all your standard files (if you know how to use and run PHP on a web server for example), so that you only need to change the linking file code once for it to work across the whole website.

I've tried to give you all your options for everyone reading, but hopefully you'll find one practical enough for your specific issue Saqks. Good luck!

Comment: So you went with option one :) your local cache cleared. Nice job

Comment: My caching system was very strict. I am redoing my .htaccess :)

Comment: Good I'm glad you figured out your problem, if you found the answer useful can you please vote it up so it can help others

Answer (score 1):

Purge the cache in CloudFlare. That should fix the issue. If not change the file name to logo2 and change it in the code too. I have had this similar issue before and changing the name fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried renaming to newLogo.png? What happens then? Maybe it's some sort of cache on webserver? BTW: In your Images folder, your current "logo.png" is the one with red/black

Since you're using cloudflare, check out this link:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-

Edit:
I noticed you're using .min versions of bootstrap and jquery. I recommend to change them to the uncompressed versions. That way you get a lot more information of the error-messages in console.